# disable disassembly view while debugging

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm trying to figure out how to turn off the disassembly view in Xcode while debugging. I'd like to just keep jumping through my code instead of getting sidetracked looking through all the assembly code. I believe there was an option for this in previous versions of Xcode under the debug menu, but I can't find any options in Xcode 4.5 (latest release). Any ideas?

#### Edit:

I double checked to make sure I was in fact in my own code and not in a library, and it still does this when I am in my own code. Here is a picture of what happens:

[image: http://i1238.photobucket.com/albums/ff487/davidohyer/ScreenShot2012-10-02at35031PM.png]

This occurred by just creating a new project, making a dummy function, calling that dummy function from viewDidLoad, setting a breakpoint on the function call and stepping through using F6. Any ideas? No external libraries used. I verified that the option you mentioned is turned off when this happens.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self initVals];
}

-(void)initVals
{
    self.img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Product > Debug Workflow > **Show Disassembly While Debugging**

[image]

Remember you'll only be able to see **your own code**. Breakpoints and/or crashes that occurs inside some library or framework will just show assembly, because there's simply so source code to show.

**EDIT**

The disassembly you are showing in your edit is from `UIViewController`. You can see it in the sidebar, as well in the symbol stub comments in the disassembly.

You may break on your own code, but then, if you step from here, you'll fatally end in some framework code.

In your example, you break on the `initVals` call, from `viewDidLoad` on a `UIViewController` subclass.

If you step pass the end of this, you'll end in `UIViewController` code, as it has still a lot of stuff to do after `viewDidLoad`.

So to resume, pay attention of the symbol names on the sidebar. Here, it just shows you're not in your subclass, but in some superclass method implementation. Hence the assembly only output.

**EDIT 2**

Imagine the following code, from a library (binary only):

```
@interface Foo: NSObject

- ( void )test1;
- ( void )test2;
- ( void )test3;

@end
```

And then you subclass it:

```
@interface Bar: Foo

@end
```

Now, `Foo` does the following:

```
- ( void )test1
{
    [ self test2 ];
    [ self test3 ];
}
```

In your subclass, let's say you only override `test2`:

```
- ( void )test2
{
    ...

    /* Breakpoint here, at the end */
}
```

If you step from the breakpoint, you'll end in the `test3` superclass implementation, which is called right after `test2` from `test1`.

So you'll just jump from your own code to the superclass implementation. Here again, no human readable code to show, but only assembly.

Comment: I've checked that option, and it is already disabled. I've looked through all the settings and can't find anything else. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then you're simply not in your own code, but code from a library. So there's just no human-readable code to show.

Comment: As a side note, some useful tip: don't forget that Spotlight is quite powerful and can show you where some menu items are. So you could simply have typed "disassembly" in the spotlight field present in Xcode's Help menu, and it will show you where the setting is hidden! :)

Comment: OK, makes sense. I thought you were referring to third party libraries, didn't realize that frameworks were included in your statement. Back to my original question, when I'm debugging and the code jumps into the assembly view, what is the best way to skip to the next human readable point in the process?

Comment: Using the «step over» function (F6) is the right way. You'll stay in your own code (you'll not step into calls). But when returning from your own code, then you may still end in some framework code. No way to avoid this, except setting other breakpoints and resuming the program when you reach the end of a method you declared.

Comment: Odd. you'd think that there would be a way provided in XCode to stay in your own code the whole time.

Comment: Damn annoying if you ask me.